# V8 compile error for basic example

Tags: c++, v8

I am trying to compile the hello world example for V8, and I keep running into a compile time error. Here is the code:

```
#include <v8/src/v8.h>

using namespace v8;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  // Create a string holding the JavaScript source code.
  String source = String::New("Hi");

  // Compile it.
  Script script = Script::Compile(source) ;

  // Run it.
  Value result = script->Run();

  // Convert the result to an ASCII string and display it.
  String::AsciiValue ascii(result) ;
  printf("%s\n", *ascii) ;
  return 0;
}
```

This is the compile error:

```
error: conversion from ‘v8::Local<v8::String>’ to non-scalar type ‘v8::String’ requested
```

The error is for line 8 where it says: String source = String::New("Hi");

I have tried google'ing this error senseless, and cannot seem to find a fix for it that makes sense. Any ideas?

I have tried both:

svn checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ v8

and

svn checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/ v8

and get the same error for both.

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: The error is on line 8. I updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: The code you are trying explains in general what's going on. Real code you should use is located later in the article.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, try:

```
Local<String> source = String::New("Hi");
```

Comment: This fixed the error, but now I get a new error: undefined reference to `v8::String::New(char const*, int)'| (it doesn't reference any line in particular)

Comment: @user396404: Sounds like a linker error now.  Make sure you passed in the right libraries.

Comment: I'm already passing in v8.h. Should there be some other library?

Comment: @user396404: That's a header file, and the Javascript engine is not a header-only library.  You also need a `.lib` file (on Windows) or a `.a` or `.so` file (on Linux) at link time.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
HandleScope handle_scope;
Persistent<Context> context = Context::New();
Context::Scope context_scope(context);
Handle<String> source = String::New("'Hello' + ', World!'");
Handle<Script> script = Script::Compile(source);
TryCatch trycatch;
Handle<Value> result = script->Run();   
if ( result.IsEmpty() ) {
    Handle<Value> excep = trycatch.Exception();
    String::AsciiValue excep_str(excep);
    printf("%s\n",*excep);
}  else {
    String::AsciiValue ascii(result);
    printf("%s\n", *ascii);
}
context.Dispose();
return 0;
```